# Intersection of tangent of parabola with directix and tangent at vertex

Tags: geometry, conic-sections, coordinate-systems, reference-works

I saw this question from *Advanced Porblems in Coordinate Geometry by Vikas Gupta for JEE Advanced* pertaining to Conic Section.

> If the line $x + y −1 = 0$ is a tangent to a parabola with focus $(1, 2)$
> at $A$ and intersects the directrix at $B$ and tangent at vertex at $C$
> respectively, then $AC, BC$ is equal to :

We can solve it by forming an equation of parabola, finding slope etc. (takes about an A4 page) but that is not my concern here.

When I checked upon the authors solution to see if my approach was correct, I was amazed!
This is how the he solved the problem.

[image]

And then, the most beautiful I thing I have ever seen...$$BC*AC=(CS)^2$$

So my doubt is **how was he so certain that the circle would pass exactly through the points $A, B$ and $S$**. Is it some sort of a property or an axiom or some weird result?

I thought for a while, but nothing seems to strike. Any help would be appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: One helpful point: by definition, the distance to the focus and the distance to the directrix are equal for any point on a parabola. Therefore the dashed line segment is equal in length to $AS$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog I noticed that too...but still it isn't clicking. How can we be assured that C will be centre and the cirumference will pass through B?

Comment: $C$ *isn't* the center. The thing to prove is that $AB$ is the diameter of the circle through $ABS$.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Thanks now makes some sense but one more doubt...did he take angle BSA as 90 degree by an assumption. I mean like what if the tangent intersected some other way?

Comment: Another property of the parabola is that the tangent bisects the angle between the dashed line and $AS$ (this is why a parabolic mirror can focus light), though I don't remember how to prove this offhand. Once you have that, SAS triangle congruence gets you your right angle.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes correct, actually i did some research and found some generalized results

Comment: Hi, I'd recommend that you start putting better titles on the question so that the question's searchability increases. As an example, I have done for this question.

Comment: @Tryst with Freedom
Thank you Tryst with Freedom:). Your recent feedbacks are really helping me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Key property**: The portion of tangent between point of contact and the point where it meets directrix subtends a right angle at the focus.

Proof: Let ($ at^2, 2at$) be a point on $y^2=4ax$ with focus S. Let Q be the point where tangent at P meets directrix x= -a.

Equation of tangent is $ty=x+at^2$
Q is ($-a,\frac{-a}{t}+at$)

Slope of SP is $\frac{2at}{at^2-a}$
Slope of SQ is $\frac{\frac{-a}{t}+at}{-a-a}$

Clearly, $m_1×m_2= -1,$ hence perpendicualr.

Also, image of focus with respect to a tangent lies on directrix. So, we proved that the quadrilateral in figure is cyclic (opposite angles supplementary).

Answer (score 3):

The key is to show that angle $ASB$ is right, meaning the center of the circle through those points lies on $AB$. We do this using the dashed line segment and two known properties of the parabola:

- The dashed segment and $AS$ have the same length
- The tangent line bisects the angle between the dashed segment and $AS$

By SAS, the triangles on the two sides of $AB$ are congruent, and thus angle $ASB$ is right.

Comment: I made an answer too a little more elaborately so it would helpful for others too and I have specially mentioned you in my answer. And Thank You:) you made my day